# after filtering array, .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, loops, filter

I have a list of objects in React. I can `.map` over the objects. But I don't want them all. I need to filter based on a property. So I'm doing this:

```
const myFilteredList = myList.filter((item) => {
    return item.name === 'the filter';
  });
```

Once I do that, I cannot map over `myFilteredList`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myFilteredList.map is not a function
```

I understood this to mean that it was now an object rather than an array, so I tried this, aiming to convert it to an array:

```
let theArray = []
theArray = Object.keys(resultCampaigns).map(key => resultCampaigns[key]);
```

But I still can't map over `theArray`

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: this should work in a relatively normal environment...

Comment: can you show `myList` data?

Comment: Have you tried doing this just filtering and mapping in standalone JS?  This should work as [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will always return an Array. Can you console.log `myList` and `myFilteredList`?

Comment: after seing jkris's comment, I tried mapping over the array before returning it out of the function I'm using to build it. I can map over it within the function. Once I return it and try to map over it in my render(), I can't. This led me to believe something else was going on. Indeed, I was initializing the value within my render, so my filtered array was being overwritten. I have removed that piece, and now it's fine. Thanks for giving me a sounding board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being something unrelated to what I was trying to do, but I'll post it here so others can see. The things I was trying to do as laid out in my question will work. They didn't work for me because I was setting the value of `myFilteredList` in my `render()` by doing this:

```
const myFilteredList = this.state;
```

I believe that was overwriting my filtered array. Don't do that. I removed the above line of code, and now it's fine. I'm just accessing the array by doing

```
this.state.myFilteredList
```

rather than just `myFilteredList`

EDIT:

My real problem is outlined in a below comment. I had simply forgotten the curly braces in `const { myFilteredList } = this.state;` I have updated my code to reflect that tiny change, and it's fine now.

Comment: you can do like this as well: const {myFilteredList} = this.state;

Comment: @Ved - Oh my gosh. That's exactly what I was doing wrong. I'm using the brackets on my other vars, but for some reason, left them out on this one and did not notice. I'm adding it back in that way. Thank you.